# Porque tengo este error: [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] Content-Length mismatch, received 48887 bytes out of the expected 1476545

Tags: javascript, composer

Cada vez que voy a hacer composer update obtengo este error:
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] Content-Length mismatch, received 48887 bytes out of the expected 1476545
Tengo este problema desde hace días, he googleado mucho, y he intentado varias cosas pero nada me ha funcionado. Me pueden ayudar? Les dejo la configuracion de composer, y el composer.json.

```html
CONFIG.json

{
    "config": {
        "github-protocols": ["https", "ssh"]},
    "repositories": {
        "packagist": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packagist.org"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Revisa este hilo](https://gist.github.com/oanhnn/112f68e5b91a7dac7641bcd8b0ab13ac), allí te explican cómo resolver ese problema.

Comment: ya lo había revisado y seguí esos pasos pero mi composer.json y mi config.json estan exactamente iguales como dice el hilo

Comment: ¿Probaste también: `composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org` y también: `composer config -g github-protocols https ssh` desde la consola?